# Implementation of check marks after the Button has been activated

Tags: excel, vba, button, label, byref

The code below is the code for a label next to a button which starts certain calcualtions. When I put this code into the Tabelmodul it works just fine (when i test it through the F8 key). However, i am going to need this code for the label in the macro-modul so that when the button is pushed the Label gets startet.

The issue is when I put the code into the macromodul I Keep getting the error message "Byref argument type mismatch". Which means that some things is not defined properly.

Code in the Tablemodule:

```
Private Sub Button_Klicken()
Call prcSetLabel(probjLabel:=Label1)
End Sub

Private Sub prcSetLabel(ByRef probjLabel As MSForms.Label)
With probjLabel
.Caption = "P"
End With
End Sub
```

[image: **strong text**]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so just to clarify this code used to execute on the click event of a button called Klicken, and now you want to move it to a separate macro?  Where is the new macro located that you want to move it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the macros are where I believe they are you should be able to make the calling using this:

```
Private Sub Button_Klicken()
Call prcSetLabel Me.Label1
End Sub

Private Sub prcSetLabel(ByRef probjLabel As MSForms.Label)
With probjLabel
.Caption = "P"
End With
End Sub
```

This is assuming your label name is Label1. If not then just change that name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. My Initial code with the Label which sits in the "Mirosoft Excel Objects" section works find. But the label doesnt get activated when I push the button. When I put your code into the Module section (not into Microsoft Excel objects) I get a syntax error message regarding "Call prcSetLabel Me.Label1". The Aim is when I execute the click event of the button the Label gets activated and shows  the check mark.